# Как добавить checkbox на javascript

Tags: javascript

Как исправить чтобы еще добавлялся for в lable и проверка происходила если галочка стоит что бы дальше написать событие

```js
var inputText= document.getElementById("inputText");
var ButtonAdd= document.getElementById("ButtonAdd");
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var eledd= document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
var bRemove= document.getElementById("buttonRemove");
ButtonAdd.onclick = function(){
  var inputcheck = document.createElement("input");
  inputcheck.id="fff";
  inputcheck.type ="checkbox";

 var label1= document.createElement('label');


  label1.innerHTML=inputText.value;
  list.appendChild(inputcheck);
  list.appendChild(label1);

}

if (eledd.checked){
alert("1");
}
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
<input type="text" name="" id="inputText" > 
<button id="ButtonAdd">Add</button>
<button id="bRemove">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("ButtonAdd").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var inputText = document.getElementById("inputText");
  var list = document.getElementById('list');

  var check = document.createElement("input");
  check.type = "checkbox";
  check.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log(text.textContent);
  });

  var text = document.createElement("span");
  text.textContent = inputText.value;

  var label1 = document.createElement('label');

  label1.appendChild(check);
  label1.appendChild(text);
  list.appendChild(label1);
});

document.getElementById("ButtonRemove").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var checks = document.querySelectorAll("#list input[type=checkbox]:checked");
  checks.forEach(item => item.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(item.parentNode));
});
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
<input type="text" name="" id="inputText">
<button id="ButtonAdd">Add</button>
<button id="ButtonRemove">Remove</button>
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

```js
var inputText = document.getElementById("inputText");
var ButtonAdd = document.getElementById("ButtonAdd");
var list = document.getElementById('list');

ButtonAdd.onclick = function() {
  var inputcheck = document.createElement("input");
  inputcheck.id = "fff";
  inputcheck.type = "checkbox";

  var label1 = document.createElement('label');
  label1.setAttribute("for", "fff");

  label1.innerHTML = inputText.value;
  list.appendChild(inputcheck);
  list.appendChild(label1);

  inputcheck.onclick = function(e) {
    if (this.checked)
      console.log("1");
  };
}
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
<input type="text" name="" id="inputText">
<button id="ButtonAdd">Add</button>
```

Comment: а как удалить на кнопку <button id="bRemove">Remove </button> если они выделены?

Comment: @recile Задайте, пожалуйста, вопрос с кодом и html.

Comment: изменил в заголовке

Comment: я кнопки добавил как кнопкой Remove удалить выделенное(которое отмечено галочкой) ?